# complete a future within other future

Tags: scala, concurrency

I have an external future operation which I can override it's onOperation complete method . I want to wrap it and complete by closure of a *Promise*. however I couldn't complete that future within other future. for example :

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
def foo():Future[String] = {
  val p = Promise[String]()
  channel.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener[IoReadFuture] {
    override def operationComplete(future: IoReadFuture): Unit = {
     p.success("hello")}
  }
  p.future
}

val x = foo()
x: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = List()
x.onComplete{
  case Success(msg)  => println(s"$msg world")
  case Failure(e) => println(e.getMessage)
}
res1: Unit = ()
```

is there idiomatic way to do that **without blocking**?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand the question

Comment: That's because you are causing the current thread to sleep.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh that is a wrong statement. sleep is inside `Future{:=> }` block. That will be executed on a different thread

Comment: please see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a function which takes a `delay` as input and returns a `delayed future`.

If you want to do that, you can do it in a non-sleeping way using `Await` and `Promise`.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.concurrent.duration._


// returns a future delayed by `delay` seconds
def getDelayedFutureOfStringValue(delay: Int, value: String): Future[String] = {
  // we will use this promise for wait only
  val waitProxyPromise = Promise[Int]()
  val delayedFuture = Await.ready(waitProxyPromise.future, delay.second).map({
    case _ => value
  })
  delayedFuture
}

val helloFuture = getDelayedFutureOfStringValue(2, "hello")
```

The above amy seem like a decent implementation but it is actually not. `Await` actually blocks the thread. Sadly... there is not easy way to get a delayedFutue in a totally non-blocking way in idiomatic Scala.

You can get a nice non-blocking and non-sleeping delayed future using Timer utility from Java,

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import java.util.{Timer, TimerTask}

// delay is number of seconds
def getDelayedFutureOfStringValue(delay: Int, value: String): Future[String] = {
  val promise = Promise[String]()
  val timer = new Timer()
  val timerTask = new TimerTask {
    override def run(): Unit = promise.success(value)
  }
  timer.schedule(timerTask, delay * 1000)
  promise.future
}

val niceHelloFuture = getDelayedFutureOfStringValue(2, "hello")
```

And in case you already have a future with you and you want to use that to compose a dependant future, then its pretty easy.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

// I assume you IoReadFuture is either similar to Future or wraps the actual Future   

def foo(value: String):Future[String] = {
  val p = Promise[String]()
  channel.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener[IoReadFuture] {
    override def operationComplete(ioFuture: IoReadFuture): Unit = {
      ioFuture.future.onComplete(_ => p.success(value))
    }
  }
  p.future
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scheduleOne` of the actor scheduler is non blocking way to wait for some code to execute

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val p = Promise(doSomething())
val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
system.scheduler.scheduleOne(deplay seconds)(p.future)
val f = p.future
f.flatMap { println(s"${_}") }
```